# Open link from notification sent from parse.com

Tags: android, webview, notifications, parse-platform

I have app which is connected with parse.com. I need to send a notification(message + url) and open it in my webview app. I use broadcast receiver to receive notification.
My current version opens main page which is declared in MainActivity, but i want to open link sent in notification.

This is my code:

JSON:
{
  "alert": "Nowy post!",
  "action": "http://google.com"
}

part from MANIFEST:

public class MyCustomReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {


    try {
          String action = intent.getAction();
          String channel = intent.getExtras().getString("com.parse.Channel");
          JSONObject json = new JSONObject(intent.getExtras().getString("com.parse.Data"));

          String url = json.getString("action");
          Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
          i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
          context.getApplicationContext().startActivity(i);

        } catch (JSONException e) {
          Log.d(TAG, "JSONException: " + e.getMessage());
        }

}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using a similar implementation which is working.

Encode JSON as:

```
{ "action": "your.package.name.UPDATE_STATUS", "url": "http://google.com" }
```

Make sure your AndroidManifest has:

```
<receiver android:name="your.package.name.MyCustomReceiver" android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
            <action android:name="your.package.name.UPDATE_STATUS" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Then get the String url:

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(intent.getExtras().getString("com.parse.Data"));
String myURL = json.getString("url");
```

Don't forget to change **your.package.name** to match you application.

Answer (score 0):

This simple implementation, work perfectly for me :

Json format :

```
{ "alert": "Awesome Web site !", "url": "http://stackoverflow.com" }
```

Inside my BroadcastReceiver :

```
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    String jsonData = extras.getString( "com.parse.Data" );

    try{
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonData);
        String url = json.getString("url");
        Intent viewIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
        viewIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(viewIntent);
     }catch(JsonException e){
        .....
     }
```